# Mongodb foreach for nested collection to update/copy documents to another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have collection in following format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b988de0be31724e"),     
    "xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "Manufacture": "Toshiba"    
    "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "xyz"  
    "brand" : "manufacture"     
    },
   "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b9435dfgdf43554b"),     
    "abc" : "Apple Ihone",
    "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "abc",
    "brand" : "Company"        
    }
}
```

I want to write query and expecting query results  to create another collection with following documents.

```
{
 "title": "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
 "Manufacture":"Toshiba"        
}

{
 "title": "Apple Ihone",
 "Manufacture":"Apple"      
}
```

I formed query to get expected results but returning error.

```
db.products.find().limit( 5 ).forEach(function(myDoc) { 
    var q = {};   
    myDoc.mappingData.array.forEach(function(doc){
        q[doc]= myDoc[myDoc.mappingData.doc];
        })  
     print(q);
//q will be inserted to new collection. 



})
```

Returning error `"TypeError: myDoc.mappingData.array has no properties (shell):3"`

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic key in your documents? It's very very bad idea.

Comment: that's the way data is coming from sources and solution of the query will be removing dynamic key and having direct data in another collection.

Comment: But that is not what you are asking. You should edit your question to say that you want to change the documents structure.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the title and some description as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to update the whole collection then the `limit` on your cursor in your current code is not necessary. The error you are getting is because the `mappingData` field in the `products` collection does not have a subdocument field called `array`. From your example in the question, only the `title` subdocument field is available, and that's the one you want.

Depending on the size of the products collection, inserting the converted documents to a new collection may affect your operations. You can avoid slow insert performance with using the new unordered **[bulk insert API](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp)** that streamlines your insert operations by sending them in bulk, and even better, it gives you real feedback about what succeeded and what failed.

The following bulk insert API operation will insert to `newcollection` the desired data structure where the new documents are created within the products collection cursor's **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** loop, using the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)** to create new properties. In the bulk insert, you will be sending the operations to the server in batches of 1000 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 1000 requests:

```
var bulk = db.newcollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),   
    counter = 0;

db.products.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var document = {};
    if (doc.mappingData.title) document["title"] = doc[doc.mappingData.title];
    document["Manufacturer"] = doc.Manufacture;
    bulk.insert(document);
    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.newcollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (counter % 1000 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

With the above example, the feedback you get from the bulk API operation would be in this format:

```
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 2,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

Querying the new collection `db.newcollection.find()` will yield:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56558b0427adb60c9f7e6f8d"),
    "title" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "Manufacturer" : "Toshiba"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56558b0427adb60c9f7e6f8e"),
    "title" : "Apple Ihone",
    "Manufacturer" : undefined
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chridam for you superb solution. Can I increase the counter from 1000 to 10000 to get more performance?

Comment: The [**documentation**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) states _Write commands can accept no more than 1000 operations. The Bulk() operations in the mongo shell and comparable methods in the drivers do not have this limit_ but the real limit here is the 16MB BSON limit, as that would be the maximum size of what can be sent over the wire as what is effectively one BSON document. You would ideally want to have smaller manageable chunks that are not too big over the network and are certainly safely under 16MB.

Comment: Also have a look at this [**JIRA ticket**](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-3603)